# py_func just for CPU operations?

Tags: tensorflow

According to the docs, I can use `tf.py_func` to define my own operation. It will receive Numpy arrays and must return Numpy arrays. It's not explicitly written in the doc but I conclude from that that it will be bound to the CPU device?

If I combine this with other ops which could potentially run on GPU, will TF greedily move as much computation to the GPU and automatically transfer the memory between GPU and CPU for my `tf.py_func` op? (Just like Theano would do.)

Is there anything similar like `tf.py_func` to define a GPU operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`py_func` is an odd one -- it runs the Python code in the same Python interpreter as the interpreter used to create the op. So if your surrounding ops are GPU there will be GPU<->CPU transfers. Furthermore, there will be a copy to move data between Python address space and TensorFlow address space (ie, memcpy [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc#L445))

If you are asking how to run Python code on GPU, there's Numba. If you are asking how to have a "function"-like thing in TensorFlow GPU, there's [Defun](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/294442996b2aeff00b1bfdc7e7169f7cb35bbf3d/tensorflow/python/framework/function_test.py#L47). Generally, TensorFlow is moving in the direction of defining enough numpy features so that you won't need to use numpy, but can implement your functions with native TF primitives instead.

There's another potential way of staying in Python-land while relying on TensorFlow engine. You could make a Python wrapper that implements emulates Python numeric type [interface](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types), but delegates actual work to underlying TensorFlow engine. Kind of like how numpy implements that interface and delegates underlying work to BLAS library.

With some tricks you could make this work where the data always stays on GPU. A proof of concept implementation is overviewed [here](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/imperative/blob/master/imperative_slides.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable feedback. About `Defun`: So, inside the function, what type are the arguments? Can I implement any imperative logic there, while-loops etc? Or does it only work for scalars as in the test examples? And how does it translate that to a GPU op? In some cases, I want to write CUDA code directly. Is there also a simple Python interface like in Theano or do I need to use the C++ API for that?

Comment: Defun lets you group pieces of TensorFlow graph into repeated objects. So only TF graph ops can get executed there. TF graph supports some flow control, such as restricted while loop (does not allow side-effects or break/continue). You have to use C API to write custom CUDA kernels, here's an example -- https://github.com/MycChiu/fast-LayerNorm-TF